# Liferay scheduled job fails on missing Liferay's classes

Tags: cron, liferay, quartz-scheduler

I have a Liferay job written using [this guide](http://proliferay.com/liferay-quartz-scheduler/). I am running liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.0-ga3. The job uses `DLAppServiceUtil` to work with document library.

The job starts exactly as scheduled. But the problem is this exception:

```
Exception in thread "liferay/scheduler_dispatch-407" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service/DLAppServiceUtil
```

What's wrong?

My `pom.xml` is:

```
<!-- ... -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
    <artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0-nightly</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- ... -->
```

My job class is:

```
public class MyJob implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void receive(Message message) throws MessageListenerException {
      // DLAppServiceUtil usage...
    }

}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In Liferay 7, do not use the serviceUtil classes any more (provided you write an OSGi bundle).

Instead add

```
@Reference
DLAppService dlAppService;
```

to your component class. Look up how to make the listener a proper OSGi component. Liferay's blade-samples on github might have a template. I am on my phone which makes it hard to look up&explain everything in more detail.

If this doesn't work (as you indicate in your comment), you'll have to check your build process: Make sure that the plugin's Manifest declares the dependencies that it has on the required service. From this you can see that I'm recommending to build OSGi plugins - I'm assuming that you're not doing this, because OSGi would not start your plugin until the dependencies are resolved.

You can do so by utilizing bnd. Check the numerous Maven examples within the [blade-samples](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/master/maven) for more detail.

Comment: I switched to the non_Util version but it still fails on missing class: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service/DLAppService`

Answer (score 0):

The classes are no longer part of `portal-service`, `com.liferay.portal.kernel` is the correct artifact.

Weird that IDE doesn't complain...